# How should I add a pre-loader in my java stand alone application?

Tags: java

I have made this stand-alone application that interacts with a client application using a Socket connection in Java. I have created a waiting screen for the client which waits for the admin's response. But I am having a problem as the waiting screen or frame freezes until it gets approval from the client. I have used a gif as a way to replicate somewhat like a loader.

Also, I have not used any Thread function that could possibly cause the frame to freeze. 
Here is the code for that frame:

```
package clientvoter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class ClFrame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form ClFrame2
 */
public ClFrame2() {
    super("TBSVoting: Voter2");
    initComponents();enter code here
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    filler1 = new javax.swing.Box.Filler(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0), new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0), new java.awt.Dimension(32767, 32767));
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    filler2 = new javax.swing.Box.Filler(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0), new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0), new java.awt.Dimension(32767, 32767));
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jPanel1MouseMoved(evt);
        }
    });

    jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(163, 29, 36));

    jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(163, 29, 36));

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 48)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 204, 51));
    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/clientvoter/BLogo1 (1).png"))); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("                 THE BISHOP'S SCHOOL,PUNE");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1588, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(filler2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(filler2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(29, 29, 29))
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 123, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(1636, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(filler1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap()))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(filler1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(29, 29, 29))
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
    );

    jButton1.setText("Back");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel2.setText("Waiting for Administrator response");

    jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/clientvoter/ajax-loader (7).gif"))); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(498, 498, 498)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 443, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(697, 697, 697)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 129, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(138, 138, 138)
            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 62, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addGap(0, 695, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    new ClFrame1().setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jPanel1MouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
connection ob = new connection();

    try {
        ob.connect(Ip.IP());
      this.setVisible(false);// TODO add your handling code here:
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClFrame2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClFrame2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClFrame2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}                                  



/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

    try {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
        * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
        */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ClFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ClFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ClFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ClFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(() -> {
            new ClFrame2().setVisible(true);
        });

    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClFrame2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.Box.Filler filler1;
private javax.swing.Box.Filler filler2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: You need to do all the work in a background thread.

Comment: `"Also, I have not used any Thread function that could possibly cause the frame to freeze. Here is the code for that frame:"` -- this is completely backwards. You use threads to prevent the user interface thread from freezing. Google and read the article titled "Concurrency in Swing"

Answer (score 2):

I would be shocked if it wasn't the call to [Socket#connect()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress)) because that is a blocking function and it's being called on the UI thread. You will need to submit that on another thread and wait for a response and handle that response on the UI thread. This will allow the UI thread not to be blocked and continue normal operation.

```java
ob.connect(Ip.IP());
```

This is an **example** implementation of how you might do that in a few lines of code. The idea is to return a Future of type Boolean which will be **true** if a connection is made. It will be **false** if an exception is thrown or the connection cannot be made. This will block the single threaded executor so it's worth noting that only one connection can be made at a time from the client. You will need to **poll** for this Future result on the UI thread which can be done safely, and in a non-blocking fashion by using Future#isDone.

*This code will not worth without modifications, it's an example*.

```java
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        final Future<Boolean> connected = service.submit(() -> {
            Socket socket = new Socket();//change with your socket

            try {
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("", 8080)); // change to your inet address

                return socket.isConnected();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // log exception, important
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: @HovercraftfullOfEels I think you're commenting on the wrong post.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do your blocking work (and ideally everything that is not a UI update) in a background thread, not in the UI thread.

The UI thread is the thread responsible for drawing the interface (windows, buttons, etc...), listening to input events (clicks, key presses, etc...) and launching their listeners. If you do anything in the UI thread that blocks it, it will be stuck there until unblocked and the interface will "freeze" because the thread cannot update it or listen to the events because it is blocked. To avoid this you should run anything that is not a GUI operation in a different thread, and update the GUI using APIs like `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.